# Passing UID/PWD in REST payload in a JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest

I have to POST a number of JSON files (with ~10k values each) to a REST service, which is normally a straightforward process. The caveat is; this particular service requires that the ID and API_KEY are passed in the payload. I can execute a one-off easily, but I get a 500 error when I attempt to pass the credentials, in the payload JSON file.

**One-Off Code (works fine)**

```
import requests
import json

url = '<my-url>'
payload = {
    'client_id' :'<my-id>',
    'api_key'   :'<my-key>',
    "data": { 
                  <my-data>
          }}
head = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, headers=head, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.status_code)
```

**JSON File Example (with the ID and KEY added)**

```
[
{"client_id" :"<my-id>",
"api_key":"<my-key>",
"data":{
 {"val1": "string", "val2": "string", "val3": float}
}}
]
```

**Code To Process The JSON File**

```
import requests
import json

with open ('data.json', 'r') as payload:
    url = '<my-url>'
    head = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=head, data=payload)
    print(r.status_code)
```

I'm assuming that the JSON file isn't correct with the UID/PWD added. Any insight would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, strings must be delimited by `"` not `'`.

Since your first example works fine already, for further troubleshooting I suggest to modify it to write the JSON into a file, then see if the second version of code works fine with that file. If yes, the problem is in your current JSON file.

Comment: Thank you! That's helped to move the ball forward - I now get a 401 error. Is it not possible to read the credentials from the JSON file?   JSON example above has been updated

Comment: @FunnyChef I added further advice, but please don't change the question to invalidate an existing answer.